# C# errors in TypeScript files VS2017

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I'm learning aspnetcore mvc with angular2 and I wrote my model as follows:

```
import { Supplier } from './supplier.model';
import { Rating } from './rating.model';

export class Product {
    constructor(
        public productId?: number,
        public name?: string,
        public category?: string,
        public description?: string,
        public price?: number,
        public supplier?: Supplier,
        public ratings?: Rating[]) { }
}
```

Which shows no errors, and there shouldn't be. But if I try to build the project I get:

***Error    CS0116  A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods   SportsStore F:\Projects\mvcng2\SportsStore\ClientApp\app\models\product.model.ts***

***Error    CS1026  ) expected  SportsStore F:\Projects\mvcng2\SportsStore\ClientApp\app\models\product.model.ts***

***Error    CS1002  ; expected  SportsStore F:\Projects\mvcng2\SportsStore\ClientApp\app\models\product.model.ts***

***Error    CS1519  Invalid token ',' in class, struct, or interface member declaration SportsStore F:\Projects\mvcng2\SportsStore\ClientApp\app\models\product.model.ts***

Comment: if you want to have a user defined type create it as an `interface` instead of class.

Comment: Check the file extension associations in Visual Studio

Comment: @AluanHaddad What extensions? I double checked the files are .ts type